# Is there a way to disable reverse lookups (hostname resolving) in xinetd?

Tags: xinetd

I suspect that resolving the IP address to it's hostname on each incoming connections makes my xinetd connections slow. Is there an option somewhere which would allow me to disable reverse lookups completely on xinetd?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do it, because one of the possible values of `only_from` and `no_access` in `xinetd.conf` is the hostname.

If you're sure that the root cause for the slowness is the DNS service, then you need to check why your DNS is so slow and think of some solution (maybe some kind of DNS caching like `dnsmasq` or `named`).